# Prove that intersection of a set is an existing set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $ \bigcap S $ exists for all $S  \neq \emptyset$ using set theory axioms.

I started with $S  \neq \emptyset$ means that there is at least one $B\in S$ but I don't know what to do next and which axioms to use.

Clarification: $ \cap S=\cap_{A\in S} A = \{x| x\in A, \forall A \in S\}$

Comment: You should clarify your question. What is $\cap S$?

Comment: I *think* if we interpret $\cap S=\cap_{A\in S} A = \{x| x\in A, \forall A \in S\}$ then I think this is mainly an application of the Axiom of Specification.  Might need a bit more.  Of course I don't know if that is what $\cap S$ is supposed to mean.  (You will probably also need the axiom of regularity)

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to mean, I added the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

We know there exists a set $ z\in S\ $  as $ S\neq\phi $. Let $ \varphi(x)\equiv \forall y(y\in S\rightarrow x\in y).\ $  Then choose $y=z$ and  $ \varphi(x)\rightarrow x\in z. $ By the Axiom of comprehension,  we know $ \exists B(\forall x(x\in B\leftrightarrow x\in z\wedge\varphi(x)) $. And $ (x\in B\rightarrow(x\in z\wedge\varphi(x)) $ implies $ (x\in B\rightarrow\varphi(x)) $ and $((x\in z\wedge\varphi(x))\rightarrow x\in B)$ and $(\varphi(x)\rightarrow x\in z)$ implies $(\varphi(x)\rightarrow x\in B) $. Hence $ \exists B(\forall x(x\in B\leftrightarrow  \varphi(x)) $.